# generate_tiles.py generates tiles with discontinuities

Tags: python, openstreetmap, mapnik

I run the python script, and for 2 neighboring tiles, I get the following result:
[image]

The tile generator generates each tile independently.  How can it know where tiles generated labels that bled into other tiles?  Is there a setting that prevents the generator from generating such labels?

The script can be found at https://github.com/openstreetmap/mapnik-stylesheets.
The particular area is at level 18 in the vicinity of downtown Atlantic City, NJ.

Comment: Is the error from Qt/QML or is it from the python script?

Comment: It is from the python script.  There are no run-time errors; this is a generated .png problem.

Comment: Then you should not use the qt, qml tags.

Comment: I'm using the Qt/QML map component to do the rendering; thus the tags.  I agree with removing the tags.

Comment: I realize that this mapnik capability is now somewhat obsolete.

Comment: Even OpenStreetMap occasionally has these discontinuities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typycal mapnik behaviour. While rendering one tile, it thinks the shield must be in one place, and while rendering the neighbour, it figures out it has to go somewhere else.

What you have to do is to add or raise your `buffer-size`. See https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/33485/cut-labels-with-mapnik .

Comment: It only took a year to get a response.  The reference is perfect.  Thanks!